# stdin Java Input

Tags: java, stdin, bufferedreader

I am having problems with STDIN

I would to read the following 2 string, for example:

Input:

abc

xyz

When typing "abc", then press Enter, I get abc back. However i dont want that. I would like to type another string just like input above.

So what want is: Type abc, Enter, type xyz enter

here is my code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s; 
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && s.length() != 0){     
      System.out.println(s);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Scanners for this.

Here is an example implementing scanners:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String s = scanner.nextLine();
String s2 = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println(s + ":" + s2);

//Close scanner when finished with it:
scanner.close();
```

Here is the full documentation for further reading and examples:
[Oracle documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Thank you, thats what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is the preferred way to get input from the console. Example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
String input = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("You entered: \"" + input + "\"");
```

Scanner also has other useful methods like `nextInt` and `nextChar`.
[Full docs on Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)